# Pandas - Specifying dtype with mixed column data using read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, import, dask, large-data

I'm attempting to load in several fairly large CSV's (total: roughly 30M rows / 7GB). Some of the columns are mixed `ints` and `floats` - I want these columns as `np.float16`.

---

Ideally, the `dtype` parameter of `read_csv` would be used to make the whole importing process more efficient. But, an error is thrown for these mixed data columns.

Here is the code, and corresponding error:

```
def import_processing(filepath, cols, null_cols):
    result = pd.read_csv(filepath, header = None, names = cols.keys(), dtype = cols)
    result.drop(null_cols, axis = 1, inplace = True)
    return result

data_cols = { 'feature_0' : np.float32,
              'feature_1' : np.float32,
              'feature_2' : np.uint32,
              'feature_3' : np.uint64,
              'feature_4' : np.uint64,
              'feature_5' : np.float16,
              'feature_6' : np.float16,
              'feature_7' : np.float16,
              'feature_8' : np.float16,
              'feature_9' : np.float16,
              'feature_10' : np.float16,
              'feature_11' : np.float16,
              'feature_12' : np.float16,
              'feature_13' : np.float16,
              'feature_14' : np.float16,
              'feature_15' : np.float16,
              'feature_16' : np.float16,
              'feature_17' : np.float16,
              'feature_18' : np.float16,
              'feature_19' : np.float16,
              'feature_20' : np.float16,
              'feature_21' : np.float16,
              'feature_22' : np.float16,
              'feature_23' : np.float16,
              'feature_24' : np.float16,
              'feature_25' : 'M8[ns]',
              'feature_26' : 'M8[ns]',
              'feature_27' : np.uint64,
              'feature_28' : np.uint32,
              'feature_29' : np.uint64,
              'feature_30' : np.uint32}

files = ['./file_0.csv', './file_1.csv', './file_2.csv']
all_data = [import_processing(f, data_cols, ['feature_0', 'feature_1']) for f in files]
```

```
TypeError: Cannot cast array from dtype('O') to dtype('float16') according to the rule 'safe'
```

---

But, if I don't use the `dtype` parameter, the speed of importing is greatly slowed down as all the mixed datatype columns are imported as `dtype('O')` instead of `np.float16`.

I've been getting around this by first applying a `pd.to_numeric` (not sure why this doesn't throw the same error), which converts all columns into `np.float64` and then using an `astype()` conversion to get each column into the type I want it (including those mixed datatype columns to `np.float16`).

This process is very slow, so I was wondering if there was a better way of doing it. Currently, my (very slow) working function looks like this:

```
def import_processing(filepath, cols, null_cols):
    result = pd.read_csv(filepath, header = None, names = cols.keys())
    result.drop(null_cols, axis = 1, inplace = True)

    for c in null_cols:
        cols.pop(c, None)

    result[result.columns] = result[result.columns].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
    result = result.astype(cols)
    return result
```

---

Edit: I have read that utilising Dask (in general) is a much more efficient method of managing large datasets in Python. I've never worked with it before, and as far as I'm aware it handles many operations basically using calls to Pandas - so I imagine it'd have the same datatype issues.

Comment: That is dangerous, unless you work with an ordered dictionary: `names = cols.keys()`

Comment: Also if you don't show us `cols` we can't help you.

Comment: @IanS - I've added in some more details. Is there a better way to be doing this?

Comment: To be honest I would read everything as `float64` and then convert to `float16` afterwards. Would it avoid the TypeError?

Answer (score 0):

From the error my guess is that one of your columns is not strictly numeric, and that there is some text in your data, hence Pandas interpretting it as an object-dtype column.  It's unable to coerce this data to be of type float16.  That's just a guess though.